# Unhandled exception converting to byte

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion, byte

As the title implies, I'm getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException'" style message.  Need some help figuring out why.  I'm reading in a file that has a hex value I need to parse.  The value I'm reading it could look something like this "0x12345678" (4 bytes in length).

The first byte (note this is little endian) is 'BE' and I can get that no problem.  My issue is then trying to take the next three bytes and convert that into a human readable int. (Long story, but the program that generates the output I'm parsing takes a human readable decimal number and converts it to this LE nonsense.)

```
    string parmVal = lineF.Substring((pos + length));  // this is "0x12345678"

    string hexID = parmVal.Substring(2, 2);   // stores '12'

    byte[] testID = new byte[4];
    testID[0] = Convert.ToByte(parmVal.Substring(4, 2));  <----error here
    testID[1] = Convert.ToByte(parmVal.Substring(6, 2));
    testID[2] = Convert.ToByte(parmVal.Substring(8, 2));
    testID[3] = Convert.ToByte(0);

    decimalID = int.Parse(hexID, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);  // stores 18 (0x12)
    testIDNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(testID,0);  // stores 345678
```

Interestingly, in the code I later output these values to a CSV file, and the values I print out look correct, even though its throwing the exception.  I tried reading in the last 3 bytes the same way as the first by, but then when I do the int.Parse() on it, it gets its endian-ness backwards.  Where I'd want it to convert 0x"785634", its converting 0x"345678".

Comment: That's not possible. The error cannot be there. Are you sure the value for parmVal is 0x12345678?

Comment: The code works. Replace `lineF.Substring((pos + length))` with `"0x12345678"` and it runs without error.

Comment: This is screaming for a sanity check. Since "0x12345678" works, that cannot be what is returned by the Substring call. I would run an experiment: explicitly check the expected condition (parmVal == "0x12345678") and throw if they do not match. I suspect your throw will be called.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out the answer to specify the base 16 fixed the problem.  In my specific example that was failing, the actual value was "0xBEEFFEED",  not "0x12345678".  I changed that value in my question to make it easier to show how the "endian-ness" was flipped.  As it turns out, when I subbed in the "12345678" number, I didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify base in Convert.ToByte call.

In your case it has to be:

```
testID[0] = Convert.ToByte(parmVal.Substring(4, 2), 16);
```